# Yum: How to Fix or Remove Conflicts

Tags: linux, php, apache-2.4, yum

I'm not sure how I got to this state, but now every time I try to run yum, it ends with the following messages:

```
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: httpd24-tools conflicts with httpd-tools
Error: php54-cli conflicts with php-cli
Error: php55-cli conflicts with php-cli
Error: php54-xml conflicts with php-xml
Error: php55-common conflicts with php-common
Error: php56-xml conflicts with php-xml
Error: php54-common conflicts with php-common
Error: php54-process conflicts with php-process
Error: httpd24 conflicts with httpd
Error: php55-cli conflicts with php54-cli
Error: php55-process conflicts with php-process
Error: php56-common conflicts with php-common
Error: php54 conflicts with php
Error: php56-cli conflicts with php54-cli
Error: php55-xml conflicts with php54-xml
Error: php56-process conflicts with php54-process
Error: php56 conflicts with php54
Error: php56-cli conflicts with php-cli
Error: php56-process conflicts with php-process
Error: php56-xml conflicts with php54-xml
Error: php55-xml conflicts with php-xml
Error: php55 conflicts with php
Error: php56-common conflicts with php54-common
Error: php55-process conflicts with php54-process
Error: php56 conflicts with php
Error: php55 conflicts with php54
Error: php55-common conflicts with php54-common
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
zlib-1.2.7-10.17.amzn1.x86_64 is a duplicate with zlib-1.2.3-24.7.amzn1.i686
```

For the time being, I don't want to change my apache or PHP configuration, as there are production sites on this server.  So, I don't want to install the newer versions.

I've tried the following:

```
yum clean all
yum downgrade httpd24-tools
yum distro-sync
```

But I do need to install a nodejs site, so I need to install a bunch of new packages.  **How can I fix or remove these conflicts?**

Edit: output of yum repolist:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, priorities, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
amzn-main                                                | 2.1 kB     00:00
amzn-updates                                             | 2.5 kB     00:00
mod-pagespeed                                            |  951 B     00:00
mongodb                                                  |  951 B     00:00
0 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
repo id                           repo name                               status
amzn-main                         amzn-main-Base                          5,934
amzn-updates                      amzn-updates-Base                         467
mod-pagespeed                     mod-pagespeed                              10
mongodb                           MongoDB Repository                        279
repolist: 6,690
```

It might also be worth nothing that this server (aws instance) was created in 2011 by someone else.  So, things might be a bit dated.

**Edit II**

It turns out I made a backup of the root volume before I started this process and then promptly forgot about it (Good habits are only good, if you can remember them).  So, these hideous conflicts are gone.  I'm still getting errors as such:

```
Could not retrieve mirrorlist http://nodejs.tchol.org/mirrors/nodejs-stable-amzn1 error was
14: PYCURL ERROR 6 - ""
Error: Cannot find a valid baseurl for repo: nodejs-stable
```

Which was the original issue I was trying to solve.  Probably best as a separate question, if it continues.

Comment: It looks like you've somehow managed to install conflicting (and incompatible) packages. It being Amazon Linux, you should just get rid of it and start new instances with a more reasonable Linux distribution.

Comment: Please add the output of `yum repolist` to your question. You likely have third party or addon repositories enabled that are incompatible.

Comment: @JohnMahowald - I've added the yum repolist output to my question.

Comment: @MichaelHampton - We have started this process.  But there some things not quite working right in the new server, so we'll need to keep this one going, until we get those other issues worked out.  In my edits, I have noted this instance was created in 2011, a while ago.

Comment: Well, I would certainly try `yum --skip-broken distro-sync` and see if you can get any farther.

Comment: Have you tried to uninstall the RPMs that are installed and involved in the conflict?

Comment: @MichaelHampton - Tried yum --skip-broken distro-sync to no avail. same result.

Comment: @RedCricket - No, I haven't but that sounds like that may be what I want.  How do I do that?

Comment: @Jahmic you'll have to take a close look at the error message. For example when you see `Error: httpd24-tools conflicts with httpd-tools` you should remove `httpd-tools` by executing `rpm -e httpd-tools`. But there is definitely something wrong with the image/instance you are using.  If you have just start with a new image